# How do the GPIO Pins actually work?

Tags: robotics

I recently started learning how to use the raspberry pi for robotics but ran into some problems early on as people, everywhere I checked,  were using the gpio pins with no explanation as to why they were putting them into each pin. Some would start by putting the female end into the physical pin 7 and then not explain why not into the first or second. Please help!!

Comment: Try some of the raspberry pi tutorials https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/physical-computing

Comment: why should there be a reason for picking pin 7 other than liking the number 7?

Comment: The best tutorials I found explaining ***how the GPIO pins actually work*** are the following:
(1) Digital Buffer Tutorial - Electronics Tutorials
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/logic_9.html

(2) Pull-up Resistors - Electronics Tutorials
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/pull-up-resistor.html. Happy reading. Cheers.

Comment: Of course you can dig deeper to say, logic gates, to know what the hell are are those weirdly looking "electronics symbols" etc mean. Oh, yes, there is also the "analog" stuff (Operational Amplifier etc) you don't know about.  But then life is too short to learn everything, In This Wonderful World: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4GLAKEjU4w . Happy  living. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Study the Raspberry Pi pin-out.  There are power pins, ground pins, and pins connected to General Purpose Input Output (GPIO).

All the GPIO may be used to read and write digital values.  Some of the GPIO can also implement specialist features such as serial links, SPI buses, I2C buses etc.

I suggest you study https://pinout.xyz/

Comment: Are there any videos you suggest?